# "No enclosing instance of type" error while calling method from another class in Android

Tags: android, methods, android-asynctask, instance

Colleagues, I have the such question:
1. In my first class I have the

```
public class parseYouTubeAndYahoo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<VideoDataDescription>>
```

to parse data from internet. But I need to call execute() method of this class from another class. While trying to right such code:

```
new MainActivity.parseYouTubeAndYahoo().execute("someURL");
```

I have the next error message from Eclipse

*No enclosing instance of type MainActivity is accessible. Must qualify the allocation   with an enclosing instance of type MainActivity (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of MainActivity).*

and really this problem is shrouded in fog for me. So, how to call this method from another class?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In terms of the actual error here, if `parseYouTubeAndYahoo` class is a non-static inner class inside of your Activity, then you need an instance of the enclosing class in order to instantiate the inner class. So, you'll need:

```
MainActivity myActivity = new MainActivity();
MainActivity.parseYouTubeAndYahoo asyncTask = myActivity.new parseYouTubeAndYahoo();
```

However....

You really shouldn't be instantiating non-static inner classes of your Activities from outside of the `Activity` because in order to instantiate a non-static innner class, you have to actually instantiate the enclosing class, which, in this case, is the Activity. Activities are meant to be started, not instantiated via `new`. If you have an `AsyncTask` that you'd like to use in different places, then create a new top-level class that extends from `AsyncTask`.

(For an example of creating reusable `AsyncTasks`, see: https://github.com/levinotik/ReusableAsyncTask)

Note that the syntax you've tried to use WOULD work if you needed to grab a **static** nested class. This is because in such a case, the outer class is really just acting as a namespace, but the nested class, because its static, does not actually need a reference to an instance of the outer class. Thus:

```
OuterClass.StaticNestedClass nestedObject =
     new OuterClass.StaticNestedClass();
```

is the proper syntax for getting an instance of a **static** nested class.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your `parseYouTubeAndYahoo` class is an inner class in class `MainActivity`, in Java, you should instaniate an object of the inner class by `new MainActivity().new parseYouTubeAndYahoo()`, so call that method like this `new MainActivity().new parseYouTubeAndYahoo().execute("someURL");`

I also guess `MainActivity` extends the `Activity` class, so I think the answer should be `this.new parseYouTubeAndYahoo().execute("someURL");` when you just call this method inside your `MainActivity` class.

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier just to place AsuncTask into another file as a separete class.

But if you really want to have is an inner class, then either it has to be static or you need to obtain a reference to its parent class first, which could be done like this:

in onCreate of MainActivity:

> static MainActivity activityInstance = getContext();

New method in MainActivity:

```
public static MainActivity getActivityInstance(){
  return activityInstance;
}
```

Then in another activity you can get the instance and access its public methods

> MainActivity instanceOfMainActivity = MainActivity.getInstance();

Then

> new instanceOfMainActivity.parseYouTubeAndYahoo().execute("someURL");

Answer (score 1):

Reference the context of activity to other class and use it.

Like that: public oneofconstructer(Context ctx, .....)