# Starting AsyncTask from different class file (via onReceive)

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

Can't get over it, no matter how much I search.

I have AlarmManager, where I want to start AsyncTask after every X seconds.

I do have another file, class (Alarm.class) where I have onReceive. Whatever I put inside it, will get activated perfectly.

Now I have problem. I have AsyncTask whats in my main thread/class (Onime). It does many tasks, including downloading some content.

Now problem is, how can I start that AsyncTask from another class. Sadly static didnt work, because asyc included some stuff what doesn't allow static. Is it possible via some kind of service

```
public class Alarm extends BroadcastReceiver 
{    
     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
     {   
         // Put here YOUR code.
         Log.d("alarminfo", "Alarm works!"); 


     }

 public void SetAlarm(Context context)
 {
     AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent i = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
     Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
     time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     time.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), 1000*60*1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
     Log.d("alarminfo", "Set alarm!"); 
 }

 public void CancelAlarm(Context context)
 {
     Log.d("alarminfo", "End alarm!"); 
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Alarm.class);
     PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.cancel(sender);
 }
}
```

Thats Alarm Class.

Here is Async (Its in Onime.class (different file):

```
class animeUpdator extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Anime>, Integer, String> {

        class Connection implements Runnable {

            public void run () {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL("http://xxx.com");
                        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                        String line;
                        count = 1;
                        anime_list.clear();
                        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            parsingAnime(line);
                            count += 1;
                        }

                        bufferedReader.close();

                        MessageToMainThread(UPDATE_MAIN_GUI);

                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.d("readInfo", e.toString()); 
                    }
                }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to create a instance of a inner class, you go from its outter class:

```
Onime.animeUpdator.class.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(new Onime());
```

Note, Java Class names should start with capital. ex. AnimeUpdator;

More information, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097982/is-it-possible-to-create-an-instance-of-nested-class-using-java-reflection) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053864/no-enclosing-instance-of-type-error-while-calling-method-from-another-class-in).
Or as comment pointed out:

```
public class animeUpdator extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<Anime>, Integer, String> {
   public animeUpdator(){
          ...
   }
```

}

Comment: The thing is... animeUpdator is in "Onime" class, what is different file :/... (mainActivity)

Comment: @newest update: No enclosing instance of type Onime is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type Onime (Eg. x.new A() where x is instance of Onime. - thats problem what I got before too.

Comment: At least it doesnt show error in coding, but throws me exception: 12-17 03:18:18.829: E/AndroidRuntime(647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver xx.xx.xx.Alarm: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0 - and I think it might be already inside AsyncTask problem?

Comment: try to add a constructor. as I edited. And creating a instance of Asynctask from another class isnt' a good idea to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, it kinda works :). I do get nullpointer, but I think cause might be this time really something else. Anyway I will look into it myself. Thank you!